# Audio similarity library

Tags: java, audio, similarity, shazam

I'm trying to find something like an audio similarity library for a school project. Something simple and well documented, written in python or java preferably, that could extract feature from audio files and estimate any form of similarity basing on these. Something like [this code](http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/) could also be fine but I think I don't have the skill to do something similar on my own. A "mood extractor" could also fit my needs. This is a complicated topic but I hope that someone could help me.

Comment: You could try http://www.tagtraum.com/jipes/index.html

Comment: You need to differentiate clearly between searching *similar* songs and *recognizing* songs. These are two quite different challenges.